# Maybe too many directories in this /boot/efi/EFI?

Tags: boot

`/dev/sda1` (EFI, boot) mounts as `/boot/efi`
The tree I find therein has too many branches for my taste:

```
/boot/efi/EFI
├── BOOT
│   ├── BOOTX64.EFI
│   ├── fbx64.efi
│   ├── FSCK0000.000
│   └── mmx64.efi
├── debian
│   ├── BOOTX64.CSV
│   ├── fbx64.efi
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubx64.efi
│   ├── mmx64.efi
│   └── shimx64.efi
└── ubuntu
    ├── BOOTX64.CSV
    ├── grub.cfg
    ├── grubx64.efi
    ├── mmx64.efi
    └── shimx64.efi
```

Ubuntu was, indeed, installed briefly but is no more. I do not intend to boot nor run anything else than Debian.

The boot menu, at BIOS level, has way too many options, including one unspecified "UEFI OS", and one non-existent Ubuntu or two. Those entries do not, in fact, do anything.
Likewise, and even after a little bit of culling, `efibootmgr` still reports

```
BootOrder: 0001,0011,0012,000F,0010
Boot0001* debian
Boot000F* CD/DVD Drive
Boot0010* Hard Drive
Boot0011* ubuntu
Boot0012* UEFI OS
```

Entries #11 and #12 even reappear upon reboot after being removed.

Would I take a big risk if I deleted the aforementionned `BOOT` and `ubuntu` directories ?

Comment: Definitely not too many directories...

Comment: The bootx64.efi is a copy. After Ubuntu install it is normally a copy of shimx64.efi from Ubuntu, but Windows makes it a copy of its boot files. I would make sure it is a copy of Debian's grub/shim boot files. Bootx64.efi is a fallback or drive boot entry like booting external drive. Some systems only boot from /boot entry. see `man efibootmgr` &  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Answer (score 2):

`ubuntu` is safe to delete.

`BOOT` is normally essential for EFI boot but it's perfectly possible to live without it. I personally never delete it. It's a fallback in case other boot entries are missing or unbootable.

Comment: Thanks. There goes `ubuntu` and a little bit of clutter. I am now left with exactly one OS, so there isn't exactly something to fall back to, is it ? Anyway, I'll leave `BOOT` here for now.